# Why isn't the CSS ID the highest priority CSS rule in this case?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have built a CSS navigation header, and it's working exactly the way I want in regards to positioning, stylization, all that. This is the CSS that stylizes it:

```
#header ul {
padding:72px 0 0 0;
text-align:center;
}

#header ul, #header ul li {
margin:0;
list-style:none;
}

#header ul li {
display:inline;
}

#header ul li a {
font-size:17px; color:#69C; text-decoration:none;
display:inline-block;
height:44px;
line-height:44px;
margin:3px 6px;
padding:0 26px;
}

#header ul li a:hover {
background:#69C;
color:#FFF;
}
```

And this is the list:

```
<div id="#header">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">WHAT WE DO</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="get_started">GET STARTED TODAY!</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Pretty simple stuff (and currently viewable at http://www.pmind.com/staging, but I included the code here for potential future readers).

You may notice in the list, the final *li* has an ID assigned to it. When I add this rule to the CSS:

```
#get_started {
color:#3C0;
}
```

Nothing happens. It was my understanding that A. CSS rules that come later in the CSS document have priority over rules that come earlier, and B. CSS rules used with the ID selector had the highest priority no matter what. But clearly the blue colourization that comes from the earlier CSS rules is still taking priority over colouring the final *li* green. I tried to make sure I did my due diligence Googling for the solution, but everything I find says that IDs get the highest priority (and this has also been my understanding in practice for everything I've coded before this one issue).

Comment: Oddly putting this example in a test file that only has `<style>` with css and the `<div>` shown (no doctype, html, head or body) you do get a green result on the last item in chrome and firefox. But going to your staging url, I confirm that the behavior is different. Next time, test your example.

Comment: A note about CSS selectors. When making a selector I believe it is good practice to use the least number of selectors for the match. instead of #header ul li, use #header li, instead of #header ul li a, use #header a, if you used #header a, you could override it with a#get_started or body #get_started.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you were trying to override a selector that ***didn't*** have an ID with one that ***did***, your confusion would be spot on.

In this case, though, you're using `#get_started` (which has an ID) to override `#header ul li a` ***which also has an ID in it***.

Surely you're thinking that your ID is more specific than the `#header` ID — and you're not entirely wrong — but that's not how CSS works. It only cares about the number of IDs used in the selector, not which elements those IDs happen to target.

To figure out which of two selectors takes precedence, first count the IDs in each. If one has more IDs than the other, it wins and you're done.

If it's the same number (in this case both have one) move on to the number of classes. Again, if one has more classes than the other, it wins and you're done. In this case, both have zero classes.

So we move on to the number of tag names. Once again, if one has more tag names it wins. And here `#header ul li a` has three tags in it (`ul`, `li`, and `a`) whereas `#get_started` has none. You lose. The existing selector wins.

You could work around this with just `#header #get_started` which now has two IDs, but my preference would be to more clearly describe it as:

```
#header ul li a#get_started
```

Comment: Excellently explained. Thanks a million.

Comment: This has been confusing me for a while too - great explanation. I kinda think it should work differently, but at least I now understand that it doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

`#header ul li a` has a higher specificity than `#get_started`

You should read the w3c specs on [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity).

EDIT to add:

Just remember that although specificity is commonly written in short-hand as powers of 10, 10 elements will never be more specific than one class, and 10 classes will never be more specific than one id.

E.X.

`html body div table tbody tr td ul li a` is less specific than `.some-link-class`

Comment: @drachenstern it's your choice, you can choose to accept what jsfiddle tells you or what the official spec says. :-p

Comment: I have read them. Under some examples, it says:

    li.red.level  {}  /* a=0 b=0 c=2 d=1 -> specificity = 0,0,2,1 */
    #x34y         {}  /* a=0 b=1 c=0 d=0 -> specificity = 0,1,0,0 */

Meaning that something with an ID has a score of 100.

Comment: @Michael Davis Both the selectors in this case have an ID. So both start with a score of "100", but then `#header ul li a` also getes three points for tag names, so it's "103". 103 > 100.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the excellent video:

[Understanding CSS Specificity](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=In78mSOHmls)

Answer (score 0):

can you try this

```
#get_started {
color:#3C0!important; // this will take the priority
}
```

Comment: !important is a dirty hack in this instance, but can be useful if used VERY sparingly

Comment: @Sonny i agree, but usually those cases where !important is useful are due to problems that exist in the HTML or CSS structure.

Comment: Also, the only time I ever use !important is because I'm trying to hack my own page, and figure out what style is getting overridden from somewhere else.

Comment: Now, in all fairness, !important does actually fix Michael's problem, and the text being green IS more important than it being blue. I don't think this is so much a hack as the thing !important was created for.

Comment: Yeah, I'm more curious WHY this is happening than a work around to get the issue to go away. I can just use "#header ul li:last-child a" to assign it (which is what I ended up doing, in fact) but I want to know why the ID isn't taking precedence.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

```
#get_started:link {
    color:#3C0;
}
```